# How to give different application route in one asp.net mvc application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

I have two applications hosted under one website `http://localhost` say

1. `http://localhost/<app1>`
2. `http://localhost/<app2>`

both are asp.net MVC applications having own controllers and routes and views.

I want to navigate from application 1 to application 2 on some page click for which i need to create and give route of app1 in app2.

how can this be achieved?

I am using Url.Action method for creating links for navigations

Comment: Looks like you should have been using Areas. `Url.Action()` is for generating url's within the **same** app. Just hard code the `href` attribute in the `<a>` element

Comment: I had used areas earlier but based on one requirement that i need to deploy two applications separately for some reasons , i cannot do that. Otherwise it is easy to achieve this with areas